# alert is assigned a value but never used warning in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Gettting waring in following code i want to display meassage ,but neither it is showing nor dissmiss the button

```
function App(){
  const [mode,setMode]=useState('light');
//getting warning for below line
  const [alert,setAlert]=useState(null);

  const showAlert=(message,type)=>{
    setAlert(
    {msg : message,
    type : type
    })
  };

  const toggleMode=()=>{
    if(mode==='light'){
      setMode('dark');
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='#56595b'
      showAlert("Enable dark mode","success");
    }
    else{
      setMode('light');
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='white'
      showAlert("enable light mode","success")
    }
  }


  return(
    <Navbar title="Blog"  mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode}/>
    <Alert alert="wtf"/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//Below is Alert Component

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Alert(props) {
  return (
    <>
     props.alert  && <div className="alert alert-warning alert- 
     dismissible fade show" role="alert">
     <strong>{props.alert.type}</strong> : {props.alert.msg}
     <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
     label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

WARNING in [eslint]
I want to display alert message on screen. but it is not showing

Comment: Share Alert component as well .

Comment: Well, you are never using the `alert` value, you pass `"wtf"` into your `<Alert />` component.

Comment: On an unrelated note: refrain from using variable names that are keywords in JS, eg `alert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

`<Alert alert="wtf"/>`

Should be:

`<Alert alert={alert}/>`

That should fix the lint warning.

For that null check to work you need to remove that fragment <></>, [or place it between {}](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jsx-in-react-introduction/#:%7E:text=To%20add%20JavaScript%20code%20inside,that%20evaluates%20to%20some%20value.). In my opinion it's cleaner to just remove the fragment:

```
export default function Alert(props) {
  return (
    props.alert && (
      <div
        className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"
        role="alert"
      >
        <strong>{props.alert.type}</strong> : {props.alert.msg}
        <button
          type="button"
          className="close"
          data-dismiss="alert"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  )
}
```

As someone mentioned, "alert" is not a good variable name. [There's a list of keywords that can't be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords) , alert is not on the list but [there's window.alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), which can cause confusion later. Also may be a good idea to initialize your state with an empty object instead of `null` it's often considered a good practice. Like this for example:

```
const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState({msg:"",type:""})
```

This allows you to get better performance by removing the null check on your component like so:

```
export default function Alert(props: any) {
  return (
    <div
      className="alert alert-warning alert- dismissible fade show"
      role="alert"
    >
      <strong>{props.alert.type}</strong> : {props.alert.msg}
      <button
        type="button"
        className="close"
        data-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close"
      >
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

1. You are using Boostrap modal, but only a small piece of it
2. Closing the dialog requires you to set the `alertObj` to `null`
3. You need to use the function version for setting the `mode` state

Also, avoid simple variables names like `alert`, `string`, `window`, because these are typically reserved works for JavaScript. Make your variable more descriptive i.e. `dialogData` or something to that effect.

See the working snippet below:

```js
const { useCallback, useState } = React;

const Navbar = ({ mode, title, toggleMode }) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggleMode}>Toggle Theme</button>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

const Alert = ({ alertObj, closeAlert }) =>
  alertObj != null && (
    <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <strong>{alertObj.type}</strong>: {alertObj.msg}
      <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
          onClick={closeAlert}>
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );

const App = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light');
  const [alertObj, setAlertObj] = useState(null);

  const showAlert = useCallback((message, type) => {
    setAlertObj({ msg : message, type : type })
  }, []);

  const closeAlert = useCallback((message, type) => {
    setAlertObj(null);
  }, []);

  const toggleMode = useCallback(() => {
    setMode(currentMode => {
      if (currentMode === 'light') {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#56595b';
        showAlert("Enabled dark mode", "success");
        return 'dark';
      } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        showAlert("Enabled light mode", "success");
        return 'light';
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar title="Blog" mode={mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} />
      <Alert alertObj={alertObj} closeAlert={closeAlert} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```css
header { display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
header nav ul { display: flex; margin: 0; padding: 0; gap: 1rem; justify-content: center; }
header nav ul li { display: flex; margin: 0; padding: 0.5rem; border: thin solid grey; }
header div button { margin-top: 1rem; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```